# Axis extraction through a 2d index

Tags: python, numpy

I want to extract the result by indexing an array

```
a = np.array([[10,20,30,40,50,60],
              [15,25,35,45,55,65]])

b = np.array([[0,1,2,2,3,4,5,2,5,1,3,4,2,2,3,4,5,2,5,1],
              [0,4,5,2,5,1,3,0,2,1,2,2,3,4,5,2,5,1,3,4]])
```

Expected output：

```
a[:,b]  

[[10 20 30 30 40 50 60 30 60 20 40 50 30 30 40 50 60 30 60 20]
 [15 55 65 35 65 25 45 15 35 25 35 35 45 55 65 35 65 25 45 55]]
```

But actually got:

```
[[[10 20 30 30 40 50 60 30 60 20 40 50 30 30 40 50 60 30 60 20]
  [10 50 60 30 60 20 40 10 30 20 30 30 40 50 60 30 60 20 40 50]]

 [[15 25 35 35 45 55 65 35 65 25 45 55 35 35 45 55 65 35 65 25]
 [15 55 65 35 65 25 45 15 35 25 35 35 45 55 65 35 65 25 45 55]]]
```

I probably understand what happened, but I don't know how to do it in order to have the correct output. I hope to get help. Thank you

Comment: Is that `a[:, b]`?  Missing a comma?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bug has been corrected

Comment: What you actually got is the correct output. Try it with a smaller array, with 2 or 3 elements. In a[:,b] the ":" means for every row. So, the first row of your output will only have elements that are from the first row of A. The second row of the output will only have elements that are from the second row of B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```
In [219]: a[[[0],[1]],b]
Out[219]: 
array([[10, 20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 60, 30, 60, 20, 40, 50, 30, 30, 40, 50,
        60, 30, 60, 20],
       [15, 55, 65, 35, 65, 25, 45, 15, 35, 25, 35, 35, 45, 55, 65, 35,
        65, 25, 45, 55]])
```

The first index can also be written as `np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]`

Comment: Very complete solution Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

can add parts together, may be a sexier indexing option

```
np.stack((a[0,b[0]], a[1,b[1]]))
Out[15]: 
array([[10, 20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 60, 30, 60, 20, 40, 50, 30, 30, 40, 50, 60,
        30, 60, 20],
       [15, 55, 65, 35, 65, 25, 45, 15, 35, 25, 35, 35, 45, 55, 65, 35, 65,
        25, 45, 55]])
```